# Nodejs one table two models using loopback framework

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm new in Nodejs, and start working in loopback framework.

My problem,

I have one table for users, and I want to make two models from this table like
employee model and customer model.

// model-config.json

```
"users": {
    "dataSource": "mysqlDs",
    "public": false
  },
```

I have two different controllers "employee.controller.js","customer.controller.js"
and now I'm trying to make two models form one table and using these models in specific controller.

Here is some code of both controllers.

```
//customer.controller.js
module.exports = function customer(app) { 
    var Customer = app.models.users;

 Customer.AddCustomer(data, function (err, data) {
                console.log(data);  
 });

}

//employee.controller.js
module.exports = function employee(app) { 
    var Employee= app.models.users;
}
```

when I called a my Customer model function "AddCustomer" in customer controller, it gave me the error "undefined"

here is customer model code:

```
module.exports = function (Customer) {

   Customer.AddCustomer = function (data, cb) {}
}
```

Model files

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true

  },   

"properties": {.....}
}
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use Loopback constructs, you will need to create your base user model (do not name it `User`, or it will interfere with the built-in `User` model that comes with Loopback.

So, your base model could be something like `CustomUser`, with a CustomUser.json basing the model on `PersistedModel`:

```
{
  "name": "CustomUser",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true

  },   

"properties": {.....}
}
```

Then create two new models that extend from `CustomUser` (instead of `PersistedModel`):

Customer.json

```
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "base": "CustomUser",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true

  },   

"properties": {.....}
}
```

Employee.json:

```
{
  "name": "Employee",
  "base": "CustomUser",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true

  },   

"properties": {.....}
}
```

When you run either `datasource.automigrate()` or `datasource.autoupdate()` on your sql database, this will create 3 tables, one for each model, but the two that have `"base":"CustomUser"` will have all the fields that are also in `CustomUser`, *plus* the fields you define on `Customer` and `Employee`, respectively.